# Disable Application.OnKey behaviour Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I am using Application.OnKey in Excel 2013 to change the behavior of a specific row, when the keys `c`, `x`, and `z` are pressed.

My code is below:

In a module:

```
Public Sub SetOnKey()
    Application.OnKey "x", "Macro1"
    Application.OnKey "c", "Macro2"
    Application.OnKey "z", "Macro3"
End Sub

Public Sub UnsetOnKey()
    Application.OnKey "x"
    Application.OnKey "c"
    Application.OnKey "z"
End Sub

Public Sub MoveCellSelectorToRight()
    ' Move cell selector to the right
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1).Select
End Sub

Public Sub Macro1()
    ActiveCell.Value = "r"
    MoveCellSelectorToRight
End Sub

Public Sub Macro2()
    ActiveCell.Value = "t"
    MoveCellSelectorToRight
End Sub

Public Sub Macro3()
    ActiveCell.Value = "o"
    MoveCellSelectorToRight
End Sub
```

In my workbook:

```
Public Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
 ByVal Source As Range)

    SetOnKey
    If Not Source.Row = 6 Then UnsetOnKey
End Sub
```

If I am not in row 6, the `SetOnKey` still executes. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I think you want to use the [`SelectionChange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194470.aspx) event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your IF-Logic right:

```
If Not Source.Row = 6 Then 
  UnsetOnKey
Else
  SetOnKey
End If
```

Comment: I have already tried that. I have solved it by using the `SelectionChange` event, as  @Phylogenesis said.

Comment: your code is cleaner, but equivalent. Better even without the "not" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

it is a worksheet change you used, not selectionchange... I checked, the UnsetOnKey works fine for me.
However the simplest is to check directly in the code which cell is selected and exit if wrong one